# Is there a sane way to emulate the newer media key behavior completely on an Apple Extended Keyboard II?

Tags: macos, applescript, keyboard

The operative word here being "completely".  I recently found a nearly flawless (cosmetically and functionally) AEKII (Alps, not Mitsumis) on eBay and won it for $30.  It's an awesome keyboard and it gives me fond memories of my typing classes in elementary school, but I hate the lack of modern media keys; I used them all the time on my wired Aluminum keyboard.

My current "hack" involves some custom AppleScripts (I've only implemented volume up/down) that I imported as Alfred Extensions and bound to some custom hotkeys, but this approach has some downsides:

- No system feedback; the volume overlay and sound effect don't show up.  And I'm fairly noobish when it comes to AppleScripting so I have yet to figure out if it's possible to do this.
- Because it's a script and not a true hardware interrupt, things like system load can lead to delays in responding to the key presses.
- I can't hold down the key to affect a continuous increase or decrease.  I have to repeatedly hit the keys to repeatedly increment or decrement the volume value.

I'd imagine that there is a way to write an AppleScript that captures keypresses and I can use that to process a continuously depressed key, but I haven't found it worthwhile to spin a bunch of cycles trying to figure this out.

Are there any other AEKII users out there that have found a sane way to handle special functions from the keyboard?

Comment: Keyremap4macbook worked amazingly for me, really needed it. KVM'ing between windows and mac with a simple keyboard that didnt have an "FN" key. with keyremap i made an fn key and all was groovy in the world, thanks again. anyone trying it should just remember to click the reload xml key once you selct your mapping.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html.en):

[image]

or [FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/):

[image]

If neither works, you could also try creating a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) in KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
<name>Change F-keys</name>
<identifier>0A0FE074-9C9C-43DC-8AEB-6683C5CB3259</identifier>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::F1, KeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_DOWN</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::F2, KeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_UP</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::F3, KeyCode::MISSION_CONTROL</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::F4, KeyCode::LAUNCHPAD</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToConsumer-- KeyCode::F5, ConsumerKeyCode::KEYBOARDLIGHT_LOW</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToConsumer-- KeyCode::F6, ConsumerKeyCode::KEYBOARDLIGHT_HIGH</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToConsumer-- KeyCode::F7, ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_PREV</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToConsumer-- KeyCode::F8, ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_PLAY</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToConsumer-- KeyCode::F9, ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_NEXT</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToConsumer-- KeyCode::F10, ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_MUTE</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToConsumer-- KeyCode::F11, ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_DOWN</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToConsumer-- KeyCode::F12, ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_UP</autogen>
</item>
</root>
```

It might only work if you use the external keyboard with a laptop or have another keyboard connected. From [ConsumerKeyCode ignored - Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/keyremap4macbook/27qSt39tUb8):

> KeyRemap4MacBook requires at least one keyboard with functional keys (Volume Control, etc)
> when you want to change keys to functional keys.
>
> If possible, please connect the Apple keyboard to iMac.
>
> If you don't have another keyboard,
> please use Spark or Quicksilver or other apps to this purpose.

Comment: KeyRemap might work, as I typically use the AEKII hooked up to an MBP in clamshell with an external display.  I'll check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with [Keyboard Maestro](http://keyboardmaestro.com), as their System Volume Up/Down/Mute commands operate exactly how I want them to; I can make them work over a continuum if I hold the buttons down, and it triggers the indicator overlay and the sound effect.